# LINQ to XML .Count() method returning HEX? How to Convert it to Int?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, hex, int

I am having a problem converting a value to int.

I ran this query to count number of tags in xml file

```
 var items = (from category in xml.Descendants("category")
                         where category.Attribute("id").Value != "0"
                         select category).Count();
```

it is returning me this 0x00000002 when i am expecting it to return 2. I tried converting it to int using Convert.ToInt32 and (int)variable methods but it stays at 0x00000002. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you seeing this Hex value? Debugger, console, etc? It should be returning an int like expected. There is now hex data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

errrrr,  hex is not a data type, its just one of many ways of viewing ints.

in your debugger, deselect hex display

(right click the variable while debugging )